# Global Graph Operations gives Node Proxy not Node

Tags: java, label, neo4j

Ran this code

```
String DB_PATH = "path/to/data/graph.db"
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DB_PATH)
for(Node _node: GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDb).getAllNodesWithLabel(DynamicLabel.label('Label_Name')))
{
   //Do Stuff
}
```

However this should return nothing (have no labels in there yet).  Also it is returning not Nodes but NodeProxies with ids that don't exist in the DB.  This query was run on an fresh Neo4j 2.0 M3 database.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say it should not return anything... what does it return and what did you expect it to return? Keep in mind that it considers all and any changes in the current transaction as well.

All nodes returned from the GraphDatabaseService and friends (including GlobalGraphOperations) are NodeProxy objects, but that doesn't really matter. What's returned are objects implementing the Node interface and those contain everything required to work with the data in the database.